# How do I point to my AWS account's load balancer from another AWS account's route53 hosted zone?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

So there is my load balancer with allocated dns name and group policy - the question how my customer could link it with his hosted zone's record?

- and how I could open inbound connection for that domain name?

For now as a workaround I've created hosted zone record in my acc linked to this load balancer ... and created hosted zone record in his route53 to ip (which atm points to my record) ... BUT I think it doesn't actually point to load balancer, but only to it's node ... and I have this problem since obviously ssl certs don't match

- NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Could somebody point to right solution of this problem ... ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your customer provisions a Route 53 Alias record in the normal way, but instead of selecting the balancer from the list of targets (since it isn't shown), your customer will need to paste the DNS Name of the balancer in the box.

> If you used different accounts to create your Route 53 hosted zone and your load balancer – Enter the value that you got in the procedure [Getting the DNS Name for an ELB Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-creating.html#resource-record-sets-elb-dns-name-procedure).
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-values-alias.html

Comment: should it (DNS name) be open to world, atm it doesn't, or amazon somehow resolves it?

Comment: The DNS name for the balancer should be resolvable anywhere.  That isn't immediately/directly relevant to Alias records, since they are resolved internally to Route 53,  but if the DNS name is not resolvable from anywhere, that is unexpected. e.g. `dig my-balancer-qwertyuiop.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com` should give you at least one, usually multiple, IP addresses in response.

Comment: done, but problem NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID still presents, do my customer need sort of multi-domain SSL Certificate?

Comment: You need a certificate on the balancer that matches whatever hostname is displayed in the web browser's address bar under normal operations -- the hostname your customer is pointing to the balancer.  That is what causes `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` -- the browser is unwilling to allow the connection to proceed because it asked for one thing, but got another.